# Getting BufferQueue state in systrace

Tags: android, vsync, systrace, surfaceflinger

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how my application is interacting with the Android's buffering system. Specifically, I want to optimize when my frames are being added to SurfaceFlinger's BufferQueue, in relation to the Vsync signal.

I understand that BufferQueue information is included inside SurfaceViews when using them:

```
      Binder_1-276   (  171) [001] ...1 34110.301903: tracing_mark_write: C|171|SurfaceView|1
surfaceflinger-171   (  171) [001] ...1 34110.314233: tracing_mark_write: C|171|SurfaceView|0
```

What about if I'm using a TextureView? There is no SurfaceView counter in these cases. Is there any other indicator of buffer state when not using a SurfaceView? Do the application counters also denote BufferQueue state?

```
      Binder_2-279   (  171) [000] ...1 34169.029234: tracing_mark_write: C|171|com.android.grafika/com.android.grafika.PlayMovieActivity|1
```

The following line in both BufferQueueProducer.cpp and BufferQueueConsumer.cpp seem to suggest this, but I could use a vote of confidence if at all possible:

```
ATRACE_INT(mCore->mConsumerName.string(), mCore->mQueue.size());
```

Comment: See https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#tracking

Comment: I've read through this previously, but I don't see SurfaceView in the traces I'm looking at... I have all of the systrace categories enabled, as well.

Comment: Actually, I just grepped through a bigger set of traces... youtube does *not* have SurfaceView, but VLC *does*; do you know why this could be?

Comment: I don't know if the youtube app uses SurfaceView or TextureView (note the comments in the arch doc about SV vs. TV).  Do `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` while the app is running to see what windows SurfaceFlinger and HWC know about.  If you don't see a separate window for the video then it's probably using TextureView.  Easiest way to see the difference is to run Grafika and compare the results from the SurfaceView-based and TextureView-based video players.  (Easiest because they're pretty simple, and they share a lot of code, so you can compare them side-by-side meaningfully.)

Comment: That's a great call, I'll check that out and post my findings. By the way, thanks for your work on Graphika, that's been very useful for getting a better understanding of the graphics subsystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BufferQueue information is available in systrace/atrace/ftrace, with a few caveats.

In the traces you might see SurfaceView debug information; this will show you the BufferQueue state (but only if a SurfaceView is being used!).

```
Binder_4-1188  (  171) [000] ...1 12563.059605: tracing_mark_write: C|171|SurfaceView|1
```

In this case, BufferQueue = 1

If you need this information in a non SurfaceView application (e.g., TextureView), the data is still available under the package name:

```
Binder_2-279   (  171) [000] ...1 12668.678680: tracing_mark_write: C|171|com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.WatchWhileActivity|1
```

Furthermore, there are multiple BufferQueues, and this only tells you about the state of that BufferQueue.